# C# containers - vector,. list, queue, stack etc

Tags: c#, list, vector, stack, queue

From the similar titles I see these are probably not available in C#. because they are so basic and useful they must be there but are probably called something else.

In case they are available do they support sort/search/insert/delete/unique etc. - the usual algorithms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the classes in `System.Collections.Generic`, as well as LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 6):

The names are, for the most part, what you guessed them to be.  The [`System.Collections.Generic` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic) contains:

- [`List` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) ("vector", "list")

  - See also [`LinkedList` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1)
- [`Queue` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1) ("queue")
- [`Stack` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1) ("stack")

Since they all implement the [`IEnumerable<T>` generic interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1), you can use extension methods from the [`Enumerable` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable) with them, including [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby)/[`OrderByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending) ("sort") and [`Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct) ("unique").  Each of the three classes provides its own specific methods for adding and removing elements from the collection.

Answer (score 2):

They are available, and what's more they support the AWESOMENESS of Linq.   Which allows you to do a lot lot lot cooler stuff than just the basic algorithms you find in the C++ std library.

Comment: Disagree. What C++ and STL have is a [almost] complete implementation of sth that academia knows and a knowledgable engineer would expect for decades. On the other hand what C# has is a source or confusion and suprises "why they do not have THIS?" or "why they called a list sth that is obviously not a [linked] list?". Sure, C# containers have been maturing with each C# version but the effect is still far from being optimal.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 4.0, you have

```
System.Collections.Generic.Stack<T>
System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>
```

and many others.

For common operations on these collection classes, add `Using System.Linq;` to your C# code.

Comment: The generic collections have been available since framework 2.0. You don't need LINQ for the common operations on the collection classes. You only need that if you want to use LINQ or the LINQ extension methods on them.